# map with wrong colors but right assigned on legend?

Tags: r, dictionary, colors, legend

I've been mapping a choropleth map and when I compare the colours drawn to the numbers they re assigned to it doesn't fit.

so here is my data

```
    zip latitude    longitude   count2.x  count2.freq   reg   colorBuckets  colma
99501   61.21680    -149.87828    AK          67      Alaska     1         #EDF8FB
35010  32.90343      -85.92669    AL        1582      Alabama    3         #99D8C9
90001   33.97291    -118.24878    CA       20970    California   6         #006D2C
20001   38.90771    -77.01732     DC         952         NA      2         #CCECE6
```

so the code from the beginning that I've been using is the following

```
    library("zipcode")
library("maps")
library("plyr")
library("RColorBrewer")
colors=brewer.pal(6, "BuGn")
data(zipcode)
merge1<-merge(zipcode, tel2, by.x='zip', by.y='zip_code', all.y=TRUE)
result<- ddply(merge1, .(state), transform, count2 = count(state))
#remove NA's#
final<- result[complete.cases(result),]
#remove duplicates#
nodupl <- final[!duplicated(final$state),]
#add state to abbreviations#
nodupl$reg<-state.name[match(nodupl$count2.x, state.abb)]
#intervalle bestimmen#
nodupl$colorBuckets<- as.numeric(cut(nodupl$count2.freq, c(0,500,1000,5000,10000,15000,22000)))
#intervall legend#
text<- c("< 500", "500 - 999", "1000 - 4999","5000 - 9999", "10000 - 14999", "15000 - 22000")
#see what color is assign to where#
nodupl$colma<- colors[nodupl$colorBuckets]
map("state",regions=nodupl$reg, exact=FALSE, col = colors[nodupl$colorBuckets],  fill = TRUE,resolution = 0,lty = 0)
map("state",col = "black",fill=FALSE,add=TRUE,lty=1,lwd=1)
#legend plotten#
par(xpd=TRUE)
legend("bottomleft", text, horiz=FALSE, fill=colors)
```

so the problem is again if I see the legend the colours are assigned right but if I double check the numbers in my column (row count2.freq) with the colours on the map they don't fit. e.g california is really light colored but it should be dark. does anyone see what has been done wrong. plus I have some trouble with positioning the legend the way I have it is right on the map so Idon't see the map anymore. what could I do about that?
thanks for your help even though its saturday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The region Alaska is not available in the `map` function. Hence, your map shows the second and third entry of `nodupl$reg` (i.e., Alabama and California). But the first and second of your colours are used.

To print these states in the desired colours, use the command

```
map("state", regions=nodupl$reg[2:3], exact=FALSE,
    col = colors[nodupl$colorBuckets][2:3],  fill = TRUE,resolution = 0,lty = 0)
```

But I recommend searching a map of Alaska too.

Comment: thanks but if I search a map that includes alaska I'm gonna start again from 0 and I have to figure out all the codes again.can't I just erase the rows for this map and for the next one I need to start off new anyways. plus what would you suggest concerning my problem with the legend. how could I move it a bit out of the picture? plus additional problem I have more than this data so I would need more lines, I've tried this map("state", regions=nodupl$reg[2:6,8:10,12:44], exact=FALSE, col = colors[nodupl$colorBuckets][2:6, 8:10,12:44],  fill = TRUE,resolution = 0,lty = 0) but it did't work